# Improving complex data structure replacement

Tags: clojure

I'm attempting to modify a specific field in a data structure, described below (a filled example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/elken/e0e33146d59d4c2bf6aa2ffc73acb0de):

```
[{:fields "There are a few other fields here"
:incidents [{:fields "There are a few other fields here"
             :updates [{:fields "There are a few other fields here"
                        :content "THIS is the field I want to replace"
                        :translations [{:based_on "Based on the VALUE of this" 
                                        :content "Replace with this value"}]}]}]}]
```

I already have this implemented it in a number of functions, as below:

```
(defn- translation-content
  [arr]
  (:content (nth arr (.indexOf (map :locale arr) (env/get-locale)))))

(defn- translate
  [k coll fn & [k2]]
  (let [k2 (if (nil? k2) k k2)
        c ((keyword k2) coll)]
    (assoc-in coll [(keyword k)] (fn c))))

(defn- format-update-translation
  [update]
  (dissoc update :translations))

(defn translate-update
  [update]
  (format-update-translation (translate :content update translation-content :translations)))

(defn translate-updates
  [updates]
  (vec (map translate-update updates)))

(defn translate-incident
  [incident]
  (translate :updates incident translate-updates))

(defn translate-incidents
  [incidents]
  (vec (map translate-incident incidents)))

(defn translate-service
  [service]
  (assoc-in service [:incidents] (translate-incidents (:incidents service))))

(defn translate-services
  [services]
  (vec (map translate-service services)))
```

Each array could have any number of entries (though the number is likely less than 10).

The basic premise is to replace the `:content` in each `:update` with the relevant `:translation` based on a provided value.

My Clojure knowledge is limited, so I'm curious if there is a more optimal way to achieve this?

**EDIT**
Solution so far:

```
(defn- translation-content
  [arr]
  (:content (nth arr (.indexOf (map :locale arr) (env/get-locale)))))

(defn- translate
  [k coll fn & [k2]]
  (let [k2 (if (nil? k2) k k2)
        c ((keyword k2) coll)]
    (assoc-in coll [(keyword k)] (fn c))))

(defn- format-update-translation
  [update]
  (dissoc update :translations))

(defn translate-update
  [update]
  (format-update-translation (translate :content update translation-content :translations)))

(defn translate-updates
  [updates]
  (mapv translate-update updates))

(defn translate-incident
  [incident]
  (translate :updates incident translate-updates))

(defn translate-incidents
  [incidents]
  (mapv translate-incident incidents))

(defn translate-service
  [service]
  (assoc-in service [:incidents] (translate-incidents (:incidents service))))

(defn translate-services
  [services]
  (mapv translate-service services))
```

Comment: you can use mapv instead of (vec (map ....))

Comment: @ErtuğrulÇetin ty, amended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start more or less as you do, bottom-up, by defining some functions that look like they will be useful: how to choose a translation from among a list of translations, and how to apply that choice to an update. But I wouldn't make the functions so tiny as yours: the logic is all spread out into a lot of places, and it's not easy to get an overall idea of what is going on. Here are the two functions I'd start with:

```
(letfn [(choose-translation [translations]
          (let [applicable (filter #(= (:locale %) (get-locale))
                                   translations)]
            (when (= 1 (count applicable))
              (:content (first applicable)))))
        (translate-update [update]
          (-> update
              (assoc :content (or (choose-translation (:translations update))
                                  (:content update)))
              (dissoc :translations)))]
  ...)
```

Of course you can `defn` them instead if you'd like, and I suspect many people would, but they're only going to be used in one place, and they're intimately involved with the context in which they're used, so I like a `letfn`. These two functions are really all the interesting logic; the rest is just some boring tree-traversal code to apply this logic in the right places.

Now to build out the body of the `letfn` is straightforward, and easy to read if you make your code be the same shape as the data it manipulates. We want to walk through a series of nested lists, updating objects on the way, and so we just write a series of nested `for` comprehensions, calling `update` to descend into the right keyspace:

```
    (for [user users]
      (update user :incidents
              (fn [incidents]
                (for [incident incidents]
                  (update incident :updates
                          (fn [updates]
                            (for [update updates]
                              (translate-update update))))))))
```

I think using `for` here is miles better than using `map`, although of course they are equivalent as always. The important difference is that as you read through the code you see the new context first ("okay, now we're doing something to each user"), and then what is happening inside that context; with `map` you see them in the other order and it is difficult to keep tack of what is happening where.

Combining these, and putting them into a `defn`, we get a function that you can call with your example input and which produces your desired output (assuming a suitable definition of `get-locale`):

```
(defn translate [users]
  (letfn [(choose-translation [translations]
            (let [applicable (filter #(= (:locale %) (get-locale))
                                     translations)]
              (when (= 1 (count applicable))
                (:content (first applicable)))))
          (translate-update [update]
            (-> update
                (assoc :content (or (choose-translation (:translations update))
                                    (:content update)))
                (dissoc :translations)))]
    (for [user users]
      (update user :incidents
              (fn [incidents]
                (for [incident incidents]
                  (update incident :updates
                          (fn [updates]
                            (for [update updates]
                              (translate-update update))))))))))
```

Comment: Very useful answer, I'll give this a shot. New to functional programming, so still wrapping my head around most of it.

Comment: This answer works, but all the arrays are lists instead of vectors?

Comment: Indeed. Very often questions asked on Stack Overflow are framed in terms of vectors because that's the simplest thing to type, but lists are just as acceptable for an answer in most cases, and the code that produces lists (well, lazy-seqs really) is simpler. If you really need vectors (and from your data, it looks to me like you don't), you can easily convert it.

Answer (score 3):

we can try to find some patterns in this task (based on the contents of the snippet from github gist, you've posted):

simply speaking, you need to

1) update every item (A) in vector of data

2) updating every item (B) in vector of A's :incidents

3) updating every item (C) in vector of B's :updates

4) translating C

The `translate` function could look like this:

```
(defn translate [{translations :translations :as item} locale]
  (assoc item :content
         (or (some #(when (= (:locale %) locale) (:content %)) translations)
             :no-translation-found)))
```

it's usage (some fields are omitted for brevity):

```
user> (translate {:id 1
                  :content "abc"
                  :severity "101"
                  :translations [{:locale "fr_FR"
                                  :content "abc"}
                                 {:locale "ru_RU"
                                  :content "абв"}]}
                 "ru_RU")
;;=> {:id 1,
;;    :content "абв", 
;;    :severity "101", 
;;    :translations [{:locale "fr_FR", :content "abc"} {:locale "ru_RU", :content "абв"}]}
```

then we can see that 1 and 2 are totally similar, so we can generalize that:

```
(defn update-vec-of-maps [data k f]
  (mapv (fn [item] (update item k f)) data))
```

using it as a building block you can make up the whole data transformation:

```
(defn transform [data locale]
  (update-vec-of-maps
    data :incidents
    (fn [incidents]
      (update-vec-of-maps
        incidents :updates
        (fn [updates] (mapv #(translate % locale) updates))))))

(transform data "it_IT")
```

returns what you need.

then you can generalize it further, making the utility function for arbitrary depth transformations:

```
(defn deep-update-vec-of-maps [data ks terminal-fn]
  (if (seq ks)
    ((reduce (fn [f k] #(update-vec-of-maps % k f))
             terminal-fn (reverse ks))
     data)
    data))
```

and use it like this:

```
(deep-update-vec-of-maps data [:incidents :updates]
                         (fn [updates]
                           (mapv #(translate % "it_IT") updates)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you look at https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter

It makes it really easy to read and update clojure data structures. Same performance as hand-written code, but much shorter.

Comment: Can you show how this problem would be done in Specter?

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but the problem has been solved without the need for a dependancy.